# passing parameters to an external js files using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following script declared in the document of my head:

```
<script src="http://www.domain.com/js/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Which points to this:

**widgets.js**

```
(function () {

    var styleEl = document.createElement("link");
    styleEl.type = "text/css";
    styleEl.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8002/static/css/widgets.css";
    styleEl.rel = "stylesheet";

    //document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleEl);
    document.head.appendChild(styleEl);

    document.write("<div id='share_box'>" +
        "<a href='test' target='_blank'>R</a>" +
        "</div>");
})();
```

I would like to pass in variable to this external file, this is what I have tried:

```
<script src="widgets.js" type="text/javascript">
     var url = 'https://www.domain.com/link/'
</script>
```

How can I pass in the variable URL to my external script? (in a safe way using javascript only - no jquery)

Comment: jquery is written is javascript so when you say javascript only it makes no sense. You are mixing the DOM and javascript.Furthermore your question makes no sense at all.You say you want to pass form parameters,but where is the form?

Comment: sorry, let me explain. I want to pass a variable called url to the external js file. the variable is on the page.

Comment: The usual thing would be to declare the variable in a `<script>` tag above, and then access it. Although if you are going to have more than one you should consider using an object to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Comment: You would probably also need to notify the `widget.js` script that a change has been made to `url` somehow. Simply changing the string value of that variable won't automatically update any objects that use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links you're providing are both imaginary. There is nothing present there, however the code that you're having is as:

```
(function () {

    var styleEl = document.createElement("link");
    styleEl.type = "text/css";
    styleEl.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8002/static/css/widgets.css";
    styleEl.rel = "stylesheet";

    //document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleEl);
    document.head.appendChild(styleEl);

    document.write("<div id='share_box'>" +
        "<a href='test' target='_blank'>R</a>" +
        "</div>");
})();
```

#### Unable to pass a variable (In this example)

Actually, you cannot pass a parameter to it. Because it doesn't allow any.

#### How a function recieves a parameter

To recieve a parameter, the function must allow a parameter while declaration. Such as:

```
function someFuncName (params) {
  /* then you can say that the parameters would be sent! */
}
```

The code you're saying, won't allow any parameters because there isn't any space or permission for a param.

#### How to pass a parameter

However, to pass on a param, you use the specific term

```
<script>
  functionName(params);
</script>
```

Simple it is. But in your case, you cannot!

#### What the above code does:

What the above code actually does, is that is adds a link element. Such as

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:8002/static/css/widgets.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
```

And the next thing it does, is that it would write an element clause of

```
<div id="share_box">
  <a href="test" target="_blank">R</a>
</div>
```

Maybe the above code, would create a hyperlink and then style it using the `.css` file provided at the site that is inside the href.

But the answer is still, that you cannot pass the parameter to an external file **until or unless** it allows you to.